# error when using else in EJS. compilation error

Tags: html, node.js, express, compiler-errors, ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <%if(kindOfDay==="sunday"||kindOfDay==="saturday")%>
    <%  { %>
        <h1 style="color:pink;">Today is <%=kindOfDay%></h1>
    <%  } %>
    <%  else{%>
        <h1 style="color:blue">Today is <%=kindOfDay%></h1>
  <% }%>
  </body>
</html>
```

ERROR:Unexpected token 'else' in C:\Users\Dell\desktop\webd\todolist-v1\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't split the `} else`

This will work better

```
<% if(kindOfDay==="sunday"||kindOfDay==="saturday") { %>
  <h1 style="color:pink;">Today is <%=kindOfDay%></h1>
<% } else { %>
  <h1 style="color:blue">Today is <%=kindOfDay%></h1>
<% } %>
```

Or

```
<h1 style="color: <%= kindOfDay==="sunday"||kindOfDay==="saturday ? "pink" : "blue" %>">Today is <%=kindOfDay%></h1>
```

Or

```
<h1 class="<%=kindOfDay%>">Today is <%=kindOfDay%></h1>
```

using css

```
h1 { color: blue }
h1.sunday, h1.saturday { color: pink }
```

```css
h1 { color: blue }
h1.Sunday, h1.Saturday { color: pink }
```

```html
<h1 class="Sunday">Today is Sunday</h1>
<h1>Tomorrow is Monday</h1>
```